# Rails engines : Controller inheritance and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, routes, decorator, rails-engines

I have an engine and in my main app, I have controllers inheriting some engine's controllers.

```
class UsersController < MyEngine::UsersController

end
```

How to force my engine to use the sub-controllers without having to recreate all my routes in my main app?

---- with decorators (JensD's solution):

I added to my engine.rb file

```
config.to_prepare do
  Dir.glob(Rails.root + "app/decorators/**/my_engine/*_decorator*.rb").each do |c|
    require_dependency(c)
  end
end
```

and the decorator

```
MyEngine::MyController.class_eval do
end
```

But `super` is not possible...

A solution would be to create a sub-controller in my engine and use decorator on it but it seems strange...

Comment: There are 2 ways to accomplish this.
1. Just override the controller of the engine itself.
2. You could have a look at `class_eval` which will reevaluate your controller with the additional logic inside the "decorator" controller.

Comment: Yes, I am using the first way but the routes use the parent controller so how to force them to use the sub-controller (without rewriting).

Comment: You aren't actually overriding the controller from the engine.  You're just subclassing it which means its a completely different controller with the same behaviour of `MyEngine::UsersController`.

To override create this file:

`app/controllers/my_engine/users_controller.rb`

In this file make sure your class definition is inside a module called `MyEngine`

This will completely override the controller.

I think your best and safest bet is to go with a controller decorator. Cause you will lose all logic when completely overriding.

or rewrite your routes no other way possible.

Comment: Ok, in fact I don't want to override, this is why i use inheritance. So I try to use the decorator pattern and tell you if it's ok.

Comment: decorator pattern should be ok. Just use the same method name and call `super` everything will be ok :D

Comment: Cool, decorators work fine but I have a  `super: no superclass method` error with  `super`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use this gem for decorators instead of require_dependency:

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators

With this gem or your require_dependency you can use:

```
alias_method :super_index, :index
def index
  ...
  super_index
end
```